# Http.Post is passing parameters as null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to pass a class object from angular 6 service post call to a web api post method, api method is getting hit successfully but the class object i am passing is showing null.

AngularJS Service:-

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { User } from './user.model'
  import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from 
  '@angular/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable' ;
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class UserService {
  selectedUser: User;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  postUser(user: User) {
  debugger;
  var body = JSON.stringify(user);
  var headerOperations = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
  });
  var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, 
  headers: headerOperations })
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:54516/Account/Register', body, 
  requestOptions).map(x => x.json);
  }
  }
```

Web API Method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]       
[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void Register(User body)
{
}
```

Model Class :

```
public class User
    {       
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the Data in Action on AngularJs Side:

[image]

Lastly, Web Api Controller method with the null object:

[image]

Cors are already defined on the controller it self.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200",headers:"*", methods:"*")]
```

Comment: It means the the data you are passing of not type of User. Maybe something minor is missing.

Comment: please pass in `user` without stringify it

Comment: you dont need to use. json.stringify. pls remove it

Comment: Tried passing user directly without stringify but still the result is the same.

Comment: @nik_boyz  Fisrt: you must use httpClient https://angular.io/guide/http, not http (and forget json.stringify). Really http is "deprecated"

Comment: @Eliseo, Tried with httpclient but still the same result

Comment: @nik_boyz if you use httpClient. check what do you send to the API function. If you're using Core 2 you must add the [fromBody] attribute. The Class User in API must have the same properties that you send (it can sound stupid, but check if your'e using exacty the same property. take acount that c# is case sensitive). I think I've not forget nothing more

Comment: All the names are same. :( this is really frustrating

Comment: I have tried postman and changed the parameters to string value at both api and ui side and it worked perfectly but when i tried with the user class object it again passed null value

Answer (score 2):

For first you don't need to `stringify` the body, you can remove this line

```
var body = JSON.stringify(user);
```

and also try to add `[FromBody]` attribute to the action's parameter

```
 [AllowAnonymous]       
 [HttpPost]
 //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public void Register([FromBody]User body)
 {

 }
```

Comment: zone.js:2969 OPTIONS http://localhost:54516/Account/Register 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Failed to load http://localhost:54516/Account/Register: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415.

Comment: I have solved the above issues but still it gives a null object.

Comment: why void method? shouldn't be an `IActionResult`?

Comment: just to make it simple, In real life it is returning a view.

Comment: I have tried postman and changed the parameters to string value at both api and ui side and it worked perfectly but when i tried with the user class object it again passed null value

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 postUser(user: User) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(user);
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
        return this._http.post<any>('http://localhost:54516/Account/Register', bodyString, { headers: headers });
    }
```

and in server:

```
[AllowAnonymous]       
 [HttpPost]
 //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public void Register([FromBody]User body)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Below is the error i got:


OPTIONS http://localhost:54516/Account/Register 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Failed to load http://localhost:54516/Account/Register: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415.